# Image Magick height width

Tags: image, imagemagick

I am using below command line to obtain image properties

```
identify -format "%w %h %x %y" *.tif >> ABC.txt
```

I am getting all images properties which are present at given directory, wherein I need to search again which are less than 150dpi, lessthan 400width and lessthan 500height

I am in need of only which are contains less than / more than 150resolution, width 400 and 500height, in my output file i.e. ABC.txt.

Can anyone help me, how to obtain which are less than / greater than values, which was predefined / specified by me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you install a copy of `GNU awk` for Windows and then it is easy. Say you want files under 400px wide and under 500px high and with x & y resolution under 150, you would do

```
identify -format "%w %h %x %y\n' *.tif | awk "$1<400 && $2<500 && $3<150 && $4<150" > list.txt
```

Comment: You may want to add the filename in there `(%f)`.